# Redash: importing queries from other instance

Tags: redash

I created a new redash instance and I want to import queries from the old one.

I used this tool to export: https://gist.github.com/arikfr/598590356c4da18be976

However, when I import e.g. query 5, I get a 404 error because query 5 doesn't exist. If I create a query with id 5, importing will overwrite it.

I'm looking for a way to import without manually creating hundreds of queries

The reference for the redash API seems to amount to these few lines https://redash.io/help/user-guide/integrations-and-api/api

which arn't very helpful